# Can one rewrite $\sin(2t)$ to $\sin u$ and apply the formula $\sin u=\frac{e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}}{2i}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I have the Laplace transformation to be done for $f(t)=t\sin 4t$.
Since the first translational theorem says

$\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}=F(s)=\mathscr{L}\{e^{at}f(t)\}=F(s-a)$

I would like to put $f(t)=t$ and rewrite $\sin t$ in exponential form, by use of the formula

$\sin x=\frac{e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}}{2i}$ to rewrite sin in the exponential form. But what if $x=4t$ in $\sin x$ here?

Thanks

Comment: So are $x$, $u$ and $\phi$ the same thing?

Comment: No, using some form of substitution.

Comment: $x$, $u$ and $\phi$ must be the same $\text{mod } 2\pi$.

Comment: Impossible then! Thanks

Comment: It is because $$
\sin u = \frac{{e^{i\phi }  - e^{ - i\phi } }}{{2i}} = \sin \phi ,\quad \sin x = \frac{{e^{i\phi }  - e^{ - i\phi } }}{{2i}} = \sin \phi .
$$

Comment: Thanks, that's clear.